# Maven: resolve versions with flatten without expanding the dependencies

Tags: java, maven, version, maven-plugin, flatten

I want to resolve all the revision tags after the build, so I'm using flatten. I have a multi module project like this:

```
A (root)
|_B (parent = A, dependencyManagement with version = ${revision}
|_C (parent = B, dependencies declared in dependencyManagement without specifying the version)
```

The problem is that in the flattened pom of B the `${revision}` is not resolved. Moreover, in the flattened pom of C the version is still missing, whereas I'd expect to find the version declared in the dependencyManagement in B.

This is how I configured flatten:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                    <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten.clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tried to add this section inside `<configuration>`:

```
<pomElements>
    <dependencyManagement>expand</dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>expand</dependencies>
</pomElements>
```

This partially solves the problem, because it resolves all the version, but the pom become way too verbose, because it expands all the dependencies of the parent. So the result is that the flattened pom of C explicitly contains all the dependencies declared in B e A, and the dependencyManagement of B.

Is there a way to just solve the versions without expanding all the dependencies in the child pom?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue adding `<flattenMode>bom</flattenMode>` to `<configuration>` section in my  module containing only `dependencyManagement` section.

According to [Maven Flatten Plugin Documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/flatten-mojo.html)

> Option bom is Like ossrh but additionally keeps dependencyManagement
>   and properties. Especially it will keep the dependencyManagement as-is
>   without resolving parent influences and import-scoped dependencies.
>   This is useful if your POM represents a BOM (Bill Of Material) and you
>   do not want to deploy it as is (to remove parent and resolve version
>   variables, etc.).

You can see an example below

**Root module**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.eljaiek.autopilot</groupId>
    <artifactId>autopilot</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.0.0.M1</revision>
        <flatten.mode>clean</flatten.mode>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>autopilot-testng-runner</module>
        <module>autopilot-dependencies</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>                    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                        <flattenMode>${flatten.mode}</flattenMode>
                    </configuration>          
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten.clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**autopilot-dependencies module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>autopilot</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.eljaiek.autopilot</groupId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>autopilot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.26</slf4j.version>
        <flatten.mode>bom</flatten.mode>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>autopilot-testng-runner</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.10</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--testng-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--dependency injection-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
                <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.9</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**autopilot-testng-runner module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.eljaiek.autopilot</groupId>
        <artifactId>autopilot</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>autopilot-testng-runner</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <flatten.mode>oss</flatten.mode>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
            <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>autopilot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**autopilot-testng-runner pom flattened**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.eljaiek.autopilot</groupId>
  <artifactId>autopilot-testng-runner</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.10</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
      <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: bom has multiple problems: 
1. dependencyManagement of the parent is not resolved
2. parent is removed (so in the child's flattened pom I'm completely losing informations on the parent's dependencyManagement)
3. if I force the parent to be there by <parent>keep</parent> it doesn't resolve its revision tag.
At the moment I'm using bom with <parent>expand</parent> butthe flattened poms are too long

Comment: I tried digging into the Github code of flatten-maven-plugin, and I found out that this is an error of the flattenMode resolveCiFriendliesOnly, that resolves the revision tag of dependencyManagement only when is put on the root pom.xml. I will contribute soon to the project to improve this behaviour

Comment: I'll include my poms in my answer, since I'm not facing any issues, I use `bom` only for my dependencies module and `oss` for the other modules. I keep all my deps management in my bom module. I might help you to overcome the issue

Comment: I see your example, but what I'm saying is this: try putting autopilot-dependencies as the parent of autopilot-testng-runner. In this case, does testng-runner inherit the dependencyManagement of its parent? In my case it doesn't

Comment: Yes It does, it even  inherits the dependencies declared in the `dependencyManagement` section of the root project

Comment: Sorry, I asked you the wrong question. The problem here for me is that in your case the child inherits the dependencyManagement directly in the flattened pom of the child. What I want, instead, is to inherit it from the parent of the flattened pom. In this case I cannot use bom or oss because they remove the parent. What I want is just to resolve all the revision tags, I don't want to expand any element in the flattened pom; this is why I'm saying that I should be able to do it with resolveCiFriendliesOnly (that currently has a bug on handling the dependencyManagement)

Comment: Hi, could you please help me to for the remove issue in parent pom. i dont want to remove dependency info. if we add "bom/minimum" it is adding all the dependencies info.

Comment: @Dev do you mean using `bom/minimum` as a  `flatten.mode` value instead of `clean`  within parent pom ?